# Select parent containing specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this structure in html:

```
<ul id="resultlist">
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" value="idNumber" />
        <dl>
        ...
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

is there a one-liner method in jquery that finds the `<li>` based on the child?

currently i have this in my code to find the `<li>` but it's quite long:

```
//dynamic value
var idNumber = 2; 

//finds input with value of 2
var hiddenInput = $('#resultList').find('input[value='+idNumber+']'); 

var listItem = hiddenInput.parent();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, just chain the calls.

```
var listItem = $('#resultList input[value="'+idNumber+'"]').parent();
```

I also brought the `input` selector into the initial one to shorten it up a bit, and I also included the missing quotation marks around the attribute value.

---

You could use the non-standard `:has()` selector I suppose if you really want it...

```
var listItem = $('#resultList li:has(input[value="'+idNumber+'"])');
```

Comment: @Joseph: You're welcome. I personally don't like `:has()` because it isn't a standard selector. It's a custom one created by Sizzle, jQuery's selector engine, so you can't use it when working with plain JS.